# idate() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given

Tags: php, date

Could anyone can solve this? I don't know how to trap a date when it is over.

For example:

```
$date_expire  = '2014-07-06 13:01:00';

$date1 = new DateTime();
$date2 = new DateTime($date_expire);


if(idate('Y', $date1) >= idate('Y', $date2)){
    echo 'unlimited';
} else {
    echo 'expired';
}
```

> Error idate() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given

And I always got the `unlimited`.

Comment: the error already states it, you're feeding it with a datetime object instead of a timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the docs on [idate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.idate.php), second parameter is an integer Unix timestamp that defaults to the current local time if a timestamp is not given, so change to

```
...
if(idate('Y', strtotime($date1)) >= idate('Y', strtotime($date2))){
    echo 'unlimited';
} else {
    echo 'expired';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`idate()` belongs to the the same family of functions as  `date()`, that works with [UNIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to handle time, not `DateTime` objects.

Pass `$date->getTimestamp()` to `idate()` instead.

```
if(idate('Y', $date1->getTimestamp()) >= idate('Y', $date2->getTimestamp())){
    echo 'unlimited';
} else {
    echo 'expired';
}
```

Or better yet:

```
if ($date1->format('Y') >= $date2->format('Y'))
...
```